# Where does Ubuntu 14.04 install NetBeans

Tags: 14.04, netbeans

I revise many posts about this topic , i note that Ubuntu should install NetBeans under:

```
ln -s /usr/local/netbeans-y.y/
```

I browse `/usr/local` and i don't find any netbeans known that i have installed two versions of NetBeans

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your installation process. If you dont install it as *root*, it should be located at *~/netbeans-x.x* otherwise it is at */usr/local/netbeans-x.x*.

Answer (score 0):

Great . i found it . It is under your home directory :

```
$ ls ~ |grep net
netbeans-6.5
netbeans-8.0
```